# ASP.NET Form Authentication in balanced environment

Tags: asp.net, iis, forms-authentication, load-balancing

Getting 401 errors when trying to use ASP.NET back end in load balanced environment (2 web servers). Windows log says:

```
Event code: 4005 
Event message: Forms authentication failed for the request. Reason: The ticket supplied was invalid. 
Event time: 6/6/2012 10:34:27 AM 
Event time (UTC): 6/6/2012 5:34:27 PM 
Event ID: de68a535d53e4bdfb11ace24a97c63c9 
Event sequence: 18 
Event occurrence: 7 
Event detail code: 50201
```

Machine key on both IIS applications configured to be same. What else can cause this problem?

Comment: Yeap. it's same app - deployed to two web servers

Comment: You should also make sure both servers have identical patches, particular with respect to the MS10-070 patch: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin/MS10-070

Comment: @Aristos: I am using FormAuthentication. I don't use DB to store user sessions

Comment: @sha Yes FormAuthentcation, but where do you store your user data ?

Comment: that - ASP.NET membership tables. Yes, same DB server. Different hardware from IIS servers

Comment: @sha check that you have set the name="" and domain="" on your `<forms` on web.config - and must be the same

Comment: @Aristos - appreciate your time. It was security patches... :(

Comment: @sha Ok, no problem, happy that you solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out two web servers had slightly different set of windows patches installed. As soon as we installed all same patches on both of them - problem was solved.